# Greasemonkey script to hide stackoverflow posts?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I found myself reading the same questions over and over, so I wanted a way to hide questions.

I have a script to does what is suppose to do, however it cripples existing javascript, such as the upvote button and adding tags when asking questions. Does anyone know why this is happening, or how to fix it?

Edit: oh, in the error console I am getting:

```
Error: $ is not a function
Source File: http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=b7084478a9a4
Line: 1
```

Edit2:

## The solution

(fixed @17/06/2014)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           StackOverflowHidePosts
// @namespace      StackOverflowHidePosts
// @description    Allows you to hide questions on Stack Overflow.
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var idListString = GM_getValue('idList', '');
var idList = idListString.split(',');
GM_setValue('idList', idList.join(','));

function getId (idString)
{
    return idString.split('-')[2];
}

function removeQuestion (e)
{
    var id = getId(e.data.questionSummaryDiv.id);

    $(e.data.questionSummaryDiv).hide(250);

    idList.push(id);

    setTimeout(function() {
        GM_setValue('idList', idList.join(','));
    }, 0);

    return false;
}

$('div.question-summary').each(function (index, questionSummaryDiv)
{
    var id = getId(questionSummaryDiv.id);

    if (idList.indexOf(id) != -1)
    {
        $(questionSummaryDiv).hide();

        return;
    }

    var link = $('<a><em>(Hide Post)</em></a>');

    link.attr('href', '#' + questionSummaryDiv.id);

    link.click({questionSummaryDiv: questionSummaryDiv}, removeQuestion);

    $('div.started', questionSummaryDiv).append(link);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never inject JS if you don't have to, and never use the page's jQuery in FF GM -- that's the main source of errors in this case.

The entire script should be:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           StackOverflowImTooStupidMarker
// @namespace      StackOverflowImTooStupidMarker
// @description    Allows you to hide questions on Stack Overflow when you can't answer them.
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var idListString = GM_getValue('idList', '');
var idList = idListString.split(',');
GM_setValue('idList', idList.join(','));

function getId (idString)
{
    return idString.split('-')[2];
}

function removeQuestion (e)
{
    var id = getId(e.data.questionSummaryDiv.id);

    $(e.data.questionSummaryDiv).hide(250);

    idList.push(id);

    setTimeout(function() {
        GM_setValue('idList', idList.join(','));
    }, 0);

    return false;
}

$('div.question-summary').each(function (index, questionSummaryDiv)
{
    var id = getId(questionSummaryDiv.id);

    if (idList.indexOf(id) != -1)
    {
        $(questionSummaryDiv).hide();

        return;
    }

    var link = $('<a><em>(Too Stupid)</em></a>');

    link.attr('href', '#' + questionSummaryDiv.id);

    link.click({questionSummaryDiv: questionSummaryDiv}, removeQuestion);

    $('div.started', questionSummaryDiv).append(link);
});
```

Comment: That does not give any errors, but the script does not seem to function either. I does not hide questions, and it does not inject the "Too Stupid" link next to questions either.

Comment: I just tested it and it adds links on a question-list page and hides the question if a "Too stupid" link is clicked.  Did you just edit the script in place?  The one-time copy of jQuery doesn't always work that way. Save the code as `SO_filter.user.js`, then uninstall the old version of the GM script, and then open that file with Firefox so that GM prompts for a fresh install (and install).  That way the local copy of jQuery will be setup properly.

Comment: oh, you're right. yes, I was editing it just in place, and saving it.
removing it and adding then adding it as a new copy fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That script attempts to include jQuery first thing:

```
(function()
{
    if (typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined')
    {
        var GM_Head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement, GM_JQ = document.createElement('script');

        GM_JQ.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js';
        GM_JQ.type = 'text/javascript';
        GM_JQ.async = true;

        GM_Head.insertBefore(GM_JQ, GM_Head.firstChild);
    }        
    GM_wait();
})();
```

This issue there is that jQuery is guaranteed to be loaded on Stack Overflow to begin with...if it's not present you have much bigger issues.  That whole jQuery replacement shouldn't happen, as it's both impacting already registered plugins (nuking then) and using a newer version of jQuery that Stack Exchange currently does, meaning other potentially breaking changes as well.

Since the script needs none of the latest functionality, that entire chunk above should simply be:

```
GM_wait();
```

For the other issues, there are a few more `$` conflicts...but you still want to be safe with respect to load order here.  Here's a cheaper and still safe version that...well, works:

```
var idListString = GM_getValue('idList', '');
var idList = idListString.split(',');
GM_setValue('idList', idList.join(','));
GM_wait();

function GM_wait() {
    if (typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') {
        window.setTimeout(GM_wait, 100);
        return;
    }
    unsafeWindow.jQuery(function($) {
        var link = $('<a href="#"><em>(Too Stupid)</em></a>').click(removeQuestion);
        $('div.question-summary').each(function (index, questionSummaryDiv) {
            var id = getId(questionSummaryDiv.id);
            if (idList.indexOf(id) != -1) {
                $(questionSummaryDiv).hide();
            } else {
                $('div.started', questionSummaryDiv).append(link.clone(true));
            }
        });
    });
}
function getId (idString) {
    return idString.split('-')[2];
}
function removeQuestion () {
    var q = unsafeWindow.jQuery(this).closest("div.question-summary").hide(250);
    idList.push(getId(q.attr("id")));
    setTimeout(function() {
        GM_setValue('idList', idList.join(','));
    }, 0);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @Ron - what errors do you get in the console when running it after this change?

Comment: oh I didn't think of checking the javascript console yet. Thanks. I added the error to the main post. I assume it's because var $; is declared somewhere else, for something else too?

Comment: @Ron - there are a few other things wrong with this script too, give me a few to sort it out

Comment: Thanks for helping, I don't know if you're trying trying to fix it, but Brock already fixed it.

Comment: @Ron - He fixed it for *some* cases, it assumes load order which isn't safe for GreaseMonkey.  I added a full version above that's still safe (and a bit faster eliminating some duplicate work, only executing some when needed).  The version above should both work in all cases and speed up the load a bit.

Comment: What's this load order malarkey?  This version of the script has multiple flaws: (1) it uses `unsafeWindow` unnecessarily -- it's called unsafe for a reason. (2) it uses the page's jQuery, which means the script WILL break when the target page changes (Twitter.com broke a bunch of these kind of poorly designed scripts). (3) Because of the improper and unnecessary use of the page's jQuery, it uses timeouts that accomplish nothing and add unnecessary complexity.  Note that load order is not assumed in the simpler version of the script, it is guaranteed by the default value of `@run-at`.

Comment: @Brock - The script is using nothing complicated, it *won't* break with the page's jQuery changes to 1.7+, only if the HTML does...which is true of any user script (I've double checked this locally, btw).  In your version above you're just including/running *another* copy of jQuery on the page (SO is currently on 1.5.2)...for no reason or benefit really.

Comment: @Nick, I didn't say that the script would break if the page's jQuery changed to 1.7+, I said it would break when the page changes sometime in the future.  Sites change how they use jQuery or even *if* they do.  The advantage of using another copy for the script (which costs nothing since it loads from disk) is that (A) the script maintains insulation from the target page; sandbox isolation is a good thing; keep it AMAP. (B) The script is protected from changes to target JS. (C) JS may be disabled on the target (NoScript to the max), but a GM script (and its jQuery) will still run.

Comment: @Brock - I totally disagree here, it *does* have a cost, loading and processing that JS has a real, measurable time cost.  A) I don't see the point here, since you're explicitly intertwined in how the page is constructed anyway. B) No, it isn't, changes to our JS can still break this, but no more or less-so than using jQuery on the page. C) The site's so "broken" with JS disabled that's really not a point at all...if the purpose of the script is "I'm too stupid to answer", what's it matter when WMD (and most everything else) doesn't work either way?